# Text stuck in middle of div instead of far left

Tags: css, html

[As you can see it goes straight to the middle instead of the starting point of the div.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2akX1.png) I have set a `margin` and `width` for my `div` and when I do input an `<H1>` tag, the text just `floats` to the middle of the `div` instead of the far left where the `div` begins. I have set the `width` so it can start at that starting point not `45px` to the left.

**This is the HTML**

```
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="logo"> <img src="Pictures/bbc.png"> </div>
  <div id="signin" class="border-part"> </div>
  <div> <img id="logo-image" src="Pictures/signin.png">
    <p class="signin-text">Sign in</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dash"> <img id="dash-image" src="Pictures/bash2.png"> </div>
  <div> <img id="bell"src="Pictures/bell3.png"> </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> News </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> Sport </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> Weather </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> iPlayer </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> TV </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> Radio </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> More </div>
  <div class="seacher-border">
    <input id="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <img id="search-pic" src="Pictures/search.png"> </div>
</div>
<div id="second-bar">
  <div id="newsbar">
    <h1>NEWS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is my CSS**

```
#topbar {
    width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helmet, Freesans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    ;
}
#logo {
    margin-top: 8px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.border-part {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}
#logo-image {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 12px;
    float: left;
}
.signin-text {
    margin: 14px;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
}
#dash-image {
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
}
#bell {
    margin: 8px;
    height: 28px;
    float: left;
}
.stuff-section {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding: 13px 15px 0 15px;
    height: 27px;
}
.seacher-border {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#search-box {
    margin: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: none;
    height: 24px;
    float: left;
}
#search-pic {
    position: relative;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    height: 25px;
}
#second-bar {
    background-color: #BB1919;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
#newsbar {
    width: 1080px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 float;
}
```

Comment: so what do you want ?

Comment: I want it to stay on the left of the div instead of floating straight to the middle.

Comment: use `float:left` in `h1` tag

Comment: Didn't move it. But i am assuming that the code thinks the width i set is where the H1 tag is. Cause i tried <Float:right> and it did float all the way to the end of the div.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. It looks just fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/ygka6x7e/

Comment: Can i send a screen shot to you?

Comment: Attach it to the question, so we all could see your problem

Comment: I sent the picture in the problem

Comment: Hmm, tough one. We'll definitely need to see some more code to understand, at least I will :)

Comment: I will attach the rest of the code

Comment: I have added more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `clear: both` to `h1`:

```css
#topbar {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 40px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helmet, Freesans, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  ;
}

#logo {
  margin-top: 8px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.border-part {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
}

#logo-image {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 12px;
  float: left;
}

.signin-text {
  margin: 14px;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
}

#dash-image {
  padding-left: 50px;
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
}

#bell {
  margin: 8px;
  height: 28px;
  float: left;
}

.stuff-section {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  padding: 13px 15px 0 15px;
  height: 27px;
}

.seacher-border {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px #CCCCCC solid;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#search-box {
  margin: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #E4E4E4;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: none;
  height: 24px;
  float: left;
}

#search-pic {
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 25px;
}

#second-bar {
  background-color: #BB1919;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

#newsbar {
  width: 1080px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="logo"> <img src="Pictures/bbc.png"> </div>
  <div id="signin" class="border-part"> </div>
  <div> <img id="logo-image" src="Pictures/signin.png">
    <p class="signin-text">Sign in</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dash"> <img id="dash-image" src="Pictures/bash2.png"> </div>
  <div> <img id="bell" src="Pictures/bell3.png"> </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> News </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> Sport </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> Weather </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> iPlayer </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> TV </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> Radio </div>
  <div class="border-part stuff-section"> More </div>
  <div class="seacher-border">
    <input id="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    <img id="search-pic" src="Pictures/search.png"> </div>
</div>
<div id="second-bar">
  <div id="newsbar">
    <h1>NEWS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Jon2713 basically it return normal flow of elements after some other elements that use `float`. In other words if you use `float` and then want to start a new row just add `clear: both`. [Read more...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 4):

**A flexbox option for alignment**

```css
#second-bar {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #BB1919;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
#newsbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start; /* horizontal alignment - change to flex-end or center to see difference */
  align-items: center; /* vertical alignment */
  width: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
h1 {
  display: flex;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="second-bar">
  <div id="newsbar">
    <h1>NEWS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/zn4qkok2/

---

**A possible non-flexbox solution**

```css
#second-bar {
  background-color: #BB1919;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}
#newsbar {
  text-align: left; /* change to center or right to see difference */
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 80px; /* match to height of parent for centered vertical alignment */
  margin:0 auto;
}
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="second-bar">
  <div id="newsbar">
    <h1>NEWS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/zn4qkok2/1/

Comment: Well close but i have added a width of 1080px and that doesn't fill the screen, because it wasn't intended to, but when you add a text or picture, it suppose to be placed at the starting point of that width. When i place my text, it starts way far out instead of at the starting point.

Comment: You can edit my fiddle to show us what you mean exactly. If you don't have an account just fork it, edit it, update it and post here.

Comment: Please check the problem again because i have added a picture